# How to use handleClick for internal react components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use handleClick to link to an INTERNAL page and it's not working. If I use an actual URL for example linkUrl='https://google.com' it will work perfectly fine. But I have a problem where linkUrl only takes an ACTUAL LINK. How do I link it with an internal page instead. I tried importing the page to use it as you can see here and it didn't work.

```
import React from "react";

class Cardlist extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
      // this will open your link in new tab
      window.open(this.props.linkUrl, '_blank');
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <div className="cardlist">
        <div className="cardlist-body">
        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2><br/>
        <p>{this.props.text}</p><br/><br/>
        <button className="button-49" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.btnlink}</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default Cardlist;
```

```
import React from "react";
import Cardlist from "./Cardlist";
import Pm from "./pages/Pm";


const Services = () => {
    return(<section id="services">
    <div class="servicesContainer">
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist 
      title="Pain Management" 
      text="We offer patients the very best pain medications and treatments. We advise our patients to seek treatment for their chronic pain and learn that management is possible with the right tools [...]" 
      btnlink ="Read More" 
      linkUrl='{<Pm/>}'
    />
       
    </div>
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist 
      title="Dermatology" 
      text="The compounding pharmacist prepares therapies customized for the individual patient for a very wide range       of dermatological conditions. Such skin conditions can spell not only physical di [...]" 
      btnlink ="Read More" 
      linkUrl='your url to more info on Dermatology'
    />
    </div>

    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist
      title="Pediatric" 
      text="Children and medications often times just do not mix. Children often resist taking a medication because         they don’t like the taste. Swallowing pills is often difficult for younger children [...]" 
      btnlink ="Read More" 
      linkUrl='your url to more info on Pediatric'
    />
    </div>
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist 
      title="Hormone Replacement Therapy" 
      text="Children and medications often times just do not mix. Children often resist taking a medication because         they don’t like the taste. Swallowing pills is often difficult for younger children [...]" 
      btnlink ="Read More" 
      linkUrl='your url to more info on Hormone Replacment Terapy'
    />
    </div>
</div>
</section>);
}

export default Services;
```

Comment: What do you mean by an Internal page?

Comment: Under the pages folder in my react app, created a page called Pm.js .. would like to have the linkURL link to that page.

Comment: That's just  a react component it's not a page, If you need client-side navigation you might need something like: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: A whole router for a button click? I can’t just have my handle click link to that component. New to router, if u can give an example, would highly appreciate it.

Comment: How do you get the URL for the components then? If you don't want to use client-side routing,  you can conditionally show components, but the address bar won't change.

Comment: So it seems to me that you want to display a component in a new tab, or basically a new window...this is not possible without hoisting your entire react application into the new window/tab. But why go through all that trouble when you could instead render the new component inside a fullscreen modal? Depending on what UI library you are using, there are many ways to display a component inside a modal. I've personally used MUI Modals and it is quite simple to use a boolean to tell the modal to open and display its content. This boolean can be toggled with your `handleClick` callback

Comment: Sounds cool, would you run me an example of that using my handleClick here?

Comment: I gave a brief answer below. Also changed `Cardlist` to be a functional component because that's what I'm used to

Comment: It's giving me errors, but thanks I'll see

Comment: I really want to see how I can setup some kind of router to my linkURL from my original code, is that even possible .. can't believe it's that bad to link to another component. What's making it challenging is that I have the SAME button from the SAME card component and I want it to link to different links.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments, you can use a Popup (Modal dialog), to display the component you want to show the user.

For this example, I'm going to use MUI Dialog, which is just a variant of `Modals`. I took the example partially from one of their [demos](https://mui.com/components/dialogs/#full-screen-dialogs)

```
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import React, {useState, useCallback} from "react";

const Cardlist = ({btnlink, title, text}) => {
    const [isLinkOpen, setIsLinkOpen] = useState(false);

    handleOpenLink = useCallback(() => {
      setIsOpen(true);
    }, []);

    handleCloseLink = useCallback(() => {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }, []);

    
    return(
        <>
        <Dialog
          fullScreen
          open={isLinkOpen}
          onClose={handleCloseLink}
        >
          {btnlink}
        </Dialog>
        <div className="cardlist">
        <div className="cardlist-body">
        <h2>{title}</h2><br/>
        <p>{text}</p><br/><br/>
        <button className="button-49" onClick={handleOpenLink } />
        </div>
        </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Cardlist;
```

For the rest of the implementation, i.e. to show a "close" button, see the linked demo.